# Possible to NOT select a UIPickerView row on purpose?

Tags: ios, cocoa, uikit, uipickerview

Trying to emulate the concept of a Picker control that **forces** the user to make a selection. Is there a way to do that in iOS? [According to the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIPickerView/selectedRowInComponent:), the selectedRowInComponent function **can** return -1, which is exactly what I'm trying to accomplish, but I can't make that ever occur. I've tried not setting a row and have tried forcing the selectRow: function to accept -1, which it does without crashing, but seems to ignore it and still selects the first row. I know web sites do this all the time, so I feel like this should be available natively.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just treat the zeroth row as a special case and make the text "-- Select Option --" or just an empty string or something like that?

Comment: Yes I certainly can - and may end up doing just that. Just wanted to know if there is a way to make the PickerView not select something